# Revision view b0rken, diff links are not looking their best

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, revisions-list, google-chrome

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12061891/revisions) (using Chrome on Mac):

[image: revisions page not looking so good]

Auwie!

Comment: Did you Ctrl + F5? The layout has changed.

Comment: That does it, can be marked as resolved!

Comment: Leaving this here for now, as others in the Tavern saw the same issue. It'll be reported by others, otherwise, I fear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out a new layout has been rolled out across the network, and my browser was still caching the old CSS.

A force-refresh resolved the issue ([thanks Tim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161379/revision-view-b0rken-diff-links-are-not-looking-their-best#comment468618_161379)).

Update: As [Nick points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161379/revision-view-b0rken-diff-links-are-not-looking-their-best/161381#comment468633_161381) this was caused by a stale CDN data.

Comment: This was actually a CDN purge fail on our side, we manually kicked it and are fixing the original issue.